# Need to capture a DOM variable in GTM but the ID is dynamic and changes based on user

Tags: html, css, variables, dom, google-tag-manager

Need to return phone number in a form field as a variable in GTM, but the id is dynamic and is not being pushed to the datalayer. Wanting to pull out required value below.

```
<input name="phone" type="tel" id="id-lpvcy9p3" class="my-input" required=""
       value="1111111111" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
```

tried to regex the id (not sure regex works there) in the DOM Id field but kept getting null values

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: Might make much more sense if you used something other than the ID selector to begin with. Like, selecting that field based on its _name_ attribute.

Comment: Are you sending the phone numbers to GA4? If so, I think you risk the property being shut down due to PII data.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @CBroe that using something like `name` is a lot more solid approach than ID. With the thought that this name is unique to the field you are targeting (sometimes its not).

You can use a JavaScript variable such as `document.getElementsByName('phone')` to pull the contents of that field.